# API Call is not reloading on TableView (with MVVM)

Tags: swift, uikit

I'm building an app that works with GEODb Rapid API. It should decode country names and put them in TableView Cells.

Working with MVVM pattern and getting the result of api in my modelView.
My modelView looks as below:

```
class HomePageViewModel {

var color = UIColor.white
var apiResult: APIResult?

init() {
    getAPIResult()
}

private func getAPIResult() {
    APIHandler.urlRequest { results in
        print(results)
        self.apiResult = results
    }
}
```

}

I do get the data. Printing the result is shown as below on terminal.

```
2021-11-27 19:01:07.687230+0300 Countries[32016:2991279] [boringssl] boringssl_metrics_log_metric_block_invoke(144) Failed to log metrics

APIResult(data: [Countries.APIResultKeys(name: "Vatican City"), Countries.APIResultKeys(name: "Ethiopia"), Countries.APIResultKeys(name: "Montenegro"), Countries.APIResultKeys(name: "Namibia"), Countries.APIResultKeys(name: "Ghana")])
2021-11-27 19:03:28.937963+0300 Countries[32016:2991
```

I'm aware of boringss1 issue but will handle it later for now.

My main class is as below. I am initializing the class with the viewModel. So I'm getting the data from the main model.

```
class HomePageViewController: UIViewController {

deinit {
    print("HomePageViewController Deinit")
}

//MARK: - Computed Properties

private lazy var countriesTableView: UITableView = {
    let temp = UITableView()
    temp.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    temp.delegate = self
    temp.dataSource = self
    temp.register(CountriesTableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: CountriesTableViewCell.identifier) //Registering Cell
    
    temp.separatorStyle = .none // Removing lines out of tableView
    
    
    return temp
}()

private var viewModel: HomePageViewModel?

//MARK: - LifeCycle

init(with viewModel: HomePageViewModel) {
    self.viewModel = viewModel
    super.init(nibName: nil, bundle: nil)
    
    setupViews()
    setupConstraintsForViews()
}

required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
    fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
}
```

I'm trying to change the text label of the cell inside my main class and via the UITableView stubs as below. But the labels are not changing. I tried to reload the table view in *cellForRowAt* function but when I do that my table view just disappears.

So what am I doing wrong?
Excuse me if I'm not explaining properly.

```
extension HomePageViewController: UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 10
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        guard let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: CountriesTableViewCell.identifier, for: indexPath) as? CountriesTableViewCell else { return UITableViewCell() }
        cell.countryLabel.text = viewModel?.apiResult?.data[indexPath.row].name
        
        return cell
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
        return 60
    }
```

Comment: You have to reload the table view after receiving the data (asynchronously). And stop `guarding` the table view cell. Force unwrap it. It must not crash. If it did you made a design mistake. At the moment if the UI is not set properly you will see nothing and you have no clue why. And why is `viewModel` optional? You **do** initialize it.

Comment: Hey vadian. Thanks for answering and useful advices. Could you please elaborate the design mistake I did? I'm trying to get the data with ViewModel should I get it inside the view controller? (in order to reload the tableview after getting data, I guess I should do that but will that be MVVM safe?). Thanks again for your kind answer

Comment: I didn't say that you made a design mistake. I said that you are not able to notice one. But first of all reload the table view. The usual way is to add a completion handler and call `reloadData()` on the main thread.

Comment: Alright Vadian I got it now. Doing as below has worked to get the data on the screen. I put the data below inside indexForRowAt. Now I'll try to handle my new issues:D Thank you for your help

self.viewModel.getAPIResult {
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    cell.countryLabel.text = self.viewModel.apiResult?.data[indexPath.row].name
                    self.countriesTableView.reloadData()
                }
        }